# Is there a simpler way to write this?

Tags: c++, if-statement

Hi I'm learning the basic of C++ and I'm in the process of doing an assignment. I'm asking if there is a simpler way to write this part.

```
if ( 100 >= projectgrade && 0<= projectgrade ) {}
else 
{
    cout<<endl<<"invalid data, please retry again.";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
if ( 100 >= midtermgrade && 0<= midtermgrade ) {}
else 
{
    cout<<endl<<"invalid data, please retry again.";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
if ( 100 >= finalexamgrade && 0<= finalexamgrade ) {}
else 
{
    cout<<endl<<"invalid data, please retry again.";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Is it possible to write all those restriction in one bracket of if? I try numerous time but I can't figure it out. Ty for helping out!

Comment: Use `||` and parentheses.

Comment: I'm not sure about the wisdom of returning `EXIT_SUCCESS` on failure...

Comment: if ( 100 < projectgrade || 0 > projectgrade )

Comment: Not answering your question, but why do you use conditions like `100 >= projectgrade`? Don't you feel it's weird to put constants in the front? Use conditions such as `projectgrade <= 100`.

Comment: @YuHao it's called the Yoda technique, it means that if you make a typo and write `=` instead of `==` then the compiler diagnoses the error

Comment: @MattMcNabb I'm aware of Yoda condition. I'm against it, but even if it's considered useful, isn't it only applied to `==` only? Who would write `n >= 42` to `n = 42` by mistake? That's my point, I've seen worse in practice, such as `if (0 > foo())`, it's frustrating to read code like that.

Comment: Thank you! Yea I kinda confused you guys with the logic, sorry bout that :P

Comment: @YuHao it's only frustrating because you aren't used to it... people raise similar objections about not casting malloc, or `x & (x-1)`, etc. , the first time they see it

Comment: @MattMcNabb I'm against Yoda condition myself, but I understand why people use `if (42 == n)` instead of `if (n == 42)` and I'm fine with it. But changing `if (n >= 42)` to `if (42 <= n)` is NOT Yoda condition. There's little danger of typo `>=` to `=`, it's off the original spirit of Yoda condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ( (projectgrade <0) || (projectgrade > 100) || (midtermgrade <0) || (midtermgrade > 100) || (finalexamgrade < 0) || (finalexamgrade > 100))
{
    cout<<endl<<"invalid data, please retry again.";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: compiler show same assembly for ShotYe version and your code XD. but this one is times much more easy to read XD

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you examine your logic it's if any of the grades is less then 0 or greater then 100, so something like this -

```
if ( projectgrade < 0 || projectgrade > 100 || 
     midtermgrade < 0 || midtermgrade > 100 || 
     finalexamgrade < 0 || finalexamgrade > 100 
   ) {
  cout<<endl<<"invalid data, please retry again.";
  cin.ignore();
  cin.get();
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Edit**
and we could always add a `#define` like

```
#define range(x) x < 0 || x > 100
```

then that if could be shortened to

```
if (range(projectgrade) || range(midtermgrade) || range(finalexamgrade))
```

Comment: Do not use that range macro. It is unsafe and could result in double evaluation of `x`. Consider `range(++x)` and then realize that you might end up incrementing twice! Use a template function instead.

Comment: Use function instead of MACRO.

Answer (score 0):

In C++11 you can write:

```
auto failure = [](){
    cout << "invalid data, please try again" << endl;
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
};
```

and then use it when failures happen:

```
if ( !(100 >= projectgrade && 0<= projectgrade) )
   return failure();

// do more stuff

if ( !(100 >= midtermgrade && 0<= midtermgrade) )
    return failure();
```

Note, doing `endl` after your text instead of before it is preferable; `return 0;` always indicates success, and `cin.ignore()` just ignores a single character (in general, you may want to ignore the rest of the line).

Answer (score 0):

First you may add a function for the test

```
bool is_valid_grade(int grade)
{
    return 0 <= grade && grade <= 100;
}
```

or

```
bool is_valid_grade(unsigned int grade)
{
    return grade <= 100; // unsigned cannot be negative
}
```

then use it like:

```
if (is_valid_grade(projectgrade)
    && is_valid_grade(midtermgrade)
    && is_valid_grade(finalexamgrade))
{
    // Valid code
}
else
{
    return failure(); // your previous code into a function
}
```